# Using sweet alert instead of custom js confirms, but ending with errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, sweetalert

I am trying to use sweetalert.js instead of custom JS confirms. I was modifiying following code..

```
clear.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        
        if(confirm("Warning, this action will remove all the text data as well as your saved starting 
            and ending time")){
            localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
            localStorage.removeItem('endTime');
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      })
 })
```

code I replaced with

```
function clearConfirm(message){
        var t=false;
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: message,
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
            })
            .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                swal("file has been deleted!", {
                icon: "success",});

                t=true;
            } else {
                swal("Your data is safe!");

                t=false;
            }
        });
        
        if(t==true){
            swal("Your file is safe!");
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    clear.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        
        if(clearConfirm("all the data will get removed")==true){
            localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
            localStorage.removeItem('endTime');
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
```

As custom js returns value 'true' upon pressing 'OK' button and 'false' upon 'Cancel' button, so I tried to put the sweetalert confirm in a function and then return a true or false in above 'if' statement
.....But when I run it the function gets executed but it doesn't return value and the if condition doesnt move forward...it just pops up the confirm and after pressing OK button the desired action isn't completed(here i want to clear some data in a page)...

Please help through it.

Answer (score 0):

You have return Promise from your `clearConfirm` function and use as shown below

```js
function clearConfirm(message) {
    return swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: message,
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                swal("file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                });

                return true;
            } else {
                swal("Your data is safe!");

                return false;
            }
        });
}

clear.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    clearConfirm("all the data will get removed").then((deleted) => {
        if (deleted) {
            localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
            localStorage.removeItem('endTime');
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hey! thanks..but I have tried this too...in this case it shows up the sweetAlert confirm box and within a second without clicking OK or Cancel...it deletes the data...and it doesn't wait/let the button to be clicked to proceed and just clears off the data.

Comment: could someone suggest why this happens?...that a confirm box itself proceede with OK button and do futher things..without letting the user click either OK or Cancel button in confirm box.....coz i had tried to use QuantumAlert.js too to make confirm box, but am ending with the same thing...that it shows up the confirm dialog box but within a second proceds with OK and deletes the data.